# It possible to render a true quad (without triangles) using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to render a "true" quad in OpenGL? By that I mean a square which is *not* made out of two triangles.

Comment: What you mean is usually referred to as "quad" in rendering terms not "square".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

You can use the `GL_QUADS` primitive type instead of `GL_TRIANGLES` and draw four vertices instead of three.

But even with this, OpenGL will internally render with triangles.

Comment: Will it even increase performance then?

Comment: If you render a lot of triangles, it may reduce bandwidth consumption. Depending on the driver implementation, it could also slow down the render, especially on old graphics cards.

Comment: If I want to render 50k squares. Would you recommend 50k quads or 100k triangles?

Comment: I would try quads first but the best solution is to benchmark, on different computers if possible.

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you know if its possible to render both triangles and quads in the same 3d world? (Not 1 model using both triangles and quads, but two seperate models)

Comment: Yes you can. Note that if you use VBOs, you will have to make one VBO for quads, and one for triangles.

Comment: @Toun Data in a vertex buffer can be interpreted as any kind of primitive. It's perfectly fine to have both quad and triangle primitive data in a vertex buffer, as long as you match the right primitive type when drawing the subsets.

Comment: @LarsViklund that's right, but you will still need several draw calls.